# Image and table side-by-side, display:inline don't work in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, html-email

I created a html email, it's working correctly in Thunderbird and Gmail but not in Outlook.

I want to have side by side one image and on table.
I use display:inline in order to do that.
But Outlook show the image and below the table.

Here the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/675db7ca/1/

```
<br/>
<div style="display:inline !important"><a href="http://www.google.com/" style="text-decoration:none">
  <img border="0" height="106" width="186" src="http://pheonix.jw.lt/killercat186px.jpg" alt="logo"/>
</a></div><table cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; display:inline !important; max-width:412px; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="412">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
   <td width="200" border="0" style="vertical-align: bottom">
     <span style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:17px;color:#000000;">Super Scral</span>
     <br/>
     <span style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:16px;color:green;">Developper</span>
   </td>
  <td width="20" style="background-image: url('http://s.atchik-services.com/signature/signature_lignerouge.png');" rowspan="3">
    <div id="lignerouge"></div>
  </td>
  <td width="150" rowspan="2" border="0">
    <span style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:12px; color:#000001;"><strong>Tel</strong> : <a style="line-height:12px;padding:0px;margin:0px;color:#000001;text-decoration:none;" href="tel:0033xxxxxxxx">+33 <strong>x xx xx xx xx</strong></a>
</span>
    <br/>
    <span style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:12px; color:#000001;"><strong>Site</strong>:
<a style="line-height:12px;padding:0px;margin:0px;color:#000001;" href="http://www.google.com/">google.com</a></span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand what it is that you are asking for help on.
I'm guessing you want the image next to the text, rather than above...

Put the image in a cell in that same table

```html
<table cellspacing="0" style="max-width:412px; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="412">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><a href="http://www.google.com/" style="text-decoration:none">
  <img border="0" height="106" width="186" src="http://pheonix.jw.lt/killercat186px.jpg" alt="logo"/>
</a></td>
   <td width="200" border="0" style="vertical-align: bottom">
     <span style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:17px;color:#000000;">Super Scral</span>
     <br/>
     <span style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:16px;color:green;">Developper</span>
   </td>
  <td width="20" style="background-image: url('http://s.atchik-services.com/signature/signature_lignerouge.png');" rowspan="3">
    <div id="lignerouge"></div>
  </td>
  <td width="150" rowspan="2" border="0">
    <span style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:12px; color:#000001;"><strong>Tel</strong> : <a style="line-height:12px;padding:0px;margin:0px;color:#000001;text-decoration:none;" href="tel:0033xxxxxxxx">+33 <strong>x xx xx xx xx</strong></a>
</span>
    <br/>
    <span style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:12px; color:#000001;"><strong>Site</strong>:
<a style="line-height:12px;padding:0px;margin:0px;color:#000001;" href="http://www.google.com/">google.com</a></span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Best not to bother with divs in email if you don't know a lot about email client quirks.

Display:inline/block/etc won't work on elements like tables. Don't bother with things like that.